# Pointers problems with C

Tags: c, pointers

I don't understand the difference in the `t` and `p` pointers.  The `t` pointer gives the same output when printing `t` and `*t` only when using `**t` I get the value.

What's the difference between them?
The code is:

```
int main()
{
    int B [2][3] = {
      {2, 3, 6},
      {4, 5, 8}
    };
    int *p = B;
    int (*t)[3] = B;
    printf ("%d\n", p);
    printf ("%d\n", t);
    printf ("%d\n", *p);
    printf ("%d\n", *t);
    printf ("%d\n", **t);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
6422000
6422000
2
6422000
2
```

Comment: `int *p = B` should have given you a warning about incompatible pointer types, since B is not an int array (it's an array of arrays).

Comment: And printing pointers with `%d` is a bad idea. Use `%p`

Comment: Although both pointers have one level of *physical* indirection, they behave differently.  `*p` dereferences the pointer, while `*t` adjusts the type to `int [3]` (which will decay into `int *` in various contexts).  Addition also works differently:  Try comparing the value of `p+1` vs. `t+1`.  Also, as mentioned, don't use `%d` to print pointer values.  It isn't portable.  Use `%p`.

Comment: hey can you please explain more about the int (*t)[3] pointer its the first time I have seen anything like this and I don't understand it

Comment: replace `hey` with @mnemonc (mnemonic is name of person you are addressing.)  i.e. to reply to me specifically use @ryyker.  btw,  `(*t)[3]` is an array of three pointers to `int`

Comment: It might be more interesting to compare  `p + 1` and `t + 1`

Comment: @TomKarzes can you please explain more about the int (*t)[3] pointer its the first time I have seen anything like this and I don't understand it

Comment: @guysharon `int (*t)[3]` declares `t` to be a pointer to an array of three `int`.  This is usually used for a 2-d array.  For a 1-d array, people normally use `int *p`, which points to an `int`, and use it access the array elements.  But for a 2-d array, it needs to know the row length (e.g., 3) to know how far ahead to jump to access the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `int *p = B;` isn't a good idea but anyway, it puts the address of the very first element of `B`, 2 into `p`. So, `p` outputs the address(6422000) and `*p` outputs 2. All good till here.

What is `t`? It's a pointer to an array, `B`. What will happen when you print it, you'll get the address to `B`, which is always also the address of it's very first element, which happens to be 6422000. So, what will happen when you dereference `t`? You'll get and array, `B` in this case, which will then decay into a pointer and give you the memory address. And the memory address of `B` is 6422000. And `**t` will dereference the dereferenced array. The deference array is `B`, which will decay into the pointer, 6422000 in this case and that will be dereferenced again, giving 2.

Basically:

- `p`: Address of the very first element of `B`, 2.
- `*p`: Dereferenced `p`, in this case 2.
- `t`: Address to `B`. Address of an array is also the address of it's very first element, equivalent to `p`.
- `*t`: Dereferences into `B`, `B` will decay into it's very first element's pointer, equivalent to `p`.
- `**t`: Dereferenced `*t`, which is 2.

Note: I know, the first element of `B` is `{2, 3, 6}`, not 2. I refer to 2 as "the very first element". That's inaccurate but for the purpose of explanation, I was forced to use the terminology.

Comment: "_`p`: Address of the very first element of `B`, 2_" The first element of `B` is an `int[3]` with the values `{2,3,6}`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Read my entire answer.

Comment: Yes, it says that  the very first element of `B` is `2` - or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @Shambhav and ryyker and everyone else who answered thank you so much!!!!!! I had a really hard time understanding this 
love you all!

Answer (score 2):

Comments have addressed the importance of using the correct format specifiers, but here are a couple of other points to consider:

*point 1:*
The declaration:  `int *p = B;` should generate a compile time warning.  This is because `int *p` is a simple pointer to `int`, as such it should only be set to point to the *address of* (`&`) a single `int`.  But `B` does not represent an `int`.

For illustration, it is instructive to see the variations of warnings for the following 3 *incorrect* ways of initializing `p` with `B`.  Each starts off with the phrase:

```
_"warning: incompatible pointer types initializing `int *` with an..."_:
```

> 

```
int *p = B;//...expression of type 'int [2][3]'  
int *p = &B;//...expression of type 'int (*)[2][3]' 
int *p = &B[0]//...expression of type 'int (*)[3]'
```

Note the incompatible pointer types at the end of each warning.  Each of them is specific, providing the programmer hints how to address the potential problem.

The following initializes `*p` with the address of a single `int` and generates no warning

```
int *p = &B[0][0];//assigning address of p to the location of a single integer value.
```

*point 2:*
The following declaration/assignment:

```
int (*t)[3] = B;
```

creates `t` as a pointer to an array of 3 `int`, and points `t` to the first instance (row) of 3 `int` in `B` where `B` is defined as:

```
int B [2][3] = {{2, 3, 6}, {4, 5, 8}};
```

Because `t` is defined in this way it is flexible in the way it can be used in that it is pointable to any array of 3 `int` i.e. it does not matter how many *rows* `B` has, or to which *row* `t` is pointed.  Example, given the following arrays:

```
int B[5][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12}, {13,14,15}};
int A[3] = {0}; //A simple array of 3 int all set to 0
```

The following declarations can be made:

```
 int (*t)[3] = NULL; //points to nothing
 t = B;     //points to location of 1st element of 1st row in B   
 t = &B[1]; //points to location of 1st element of 2nd row in B
 t = &B[4]; //points to location of 1st element of 5th row in B
 t = &A;    //points to location of 1st element of A
```